# Replace missing values of a sequence in a column for each id of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe, padding

I have a dataset:

```
dt = {'id': [120,120,120,120,120,121,121,345], 'day': [0, 1,2,3,4,0,2,0], 'value': [[0.3,-0.5,-0.7],[0.5,3.4,2.7],[0.45,3.4,0.7],[0.25,0.4,0.7],[0.15,0.34,0.17],[0.35,3.4,2.7],[0.5,3.44,2.57],[0.5,0.34,0.37]]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=dt)


    day id  value
0   0   120 [0.3, -0.5, -0.7]
1   1   120 [0.5, 3.4, 2.7]
2   2   120 [0.45, 3.4, 0.7]
3   3   120 [0.25, 0.4, 0.7]
4   4   120 [0.15, 0.34, 0.17]
5   0   121 [0.35, 3.4, 2.7]
6   2   121 [0.5, 3.44, 2.57]
7   0   345 [0.5, 0.34, 0.37]
```

For each id there should be a sequence of days from 0-5. Here in my data set for the column id, some days are missing. I want to add the missing days and for those ids and add array of zeroes for the corresponding "value" column.

Result:

```
   day  id  value
0   0   120 [0.3, -0.5, -0.7]
1   1   120 [0.5, 3.4, 2.7]
2   2   120 [0.45, 3.4, 0.7]
3   3   120 [0.25, 0.4, 0.7]
4   4   120 [0.15, 0.34, 0.17]
5   0   121 [0.35, 3.4, 2.7]
6   1   121 [0, 0, 0]
7   2   121 [0.5, 3.44, 2.57]
8   3   121 [0, 0, 0]
9   4   121 [0, 0, 0]
10  0   345 [0.5, 0.34, 0.37]
11  1   345 [0, 0, 0]
12  2   345 [0, 0, 0]
13  3   345 [0, 0, 0]
14  4   345 [0, 0, 0]
```

This is the sample space. I will be doing this on a data set of huge size.

My try:

```
    r1=0
for i in df.id.unique():
    val=df.loc[df['id'] == i]
    mx=val.loc[val['day'].idxmax()].day
    for index,row in val.iterrows():
        if row.day!=r1:
            for k in range(int(row.day)-r1-1):
                a.append(np.asarray([0]*3))
            r1=row.day
        else:
            a.append(row.value)

        if(row.day==mx):
            a.append(row.value)
            for j in range(4-mx):
                a.append(np.asarray([0]*3)))
    r1=r1+1
```

But this code is not working.

How do I do this?

Comment: You *really* would be better off having a separate column for each value in your `value` column, would be much easier to deal with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`pd.MultiIndex.from_product`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html):

```
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.id.unique(), np.arange(5)], names=['id', 'day'])

out = (df.set_index(['id', 'day'])
        .reindex(idx).reset_index()
)
```

Then simply replace `NaN` with your desired fill value.

```
out.value = [d if isinstance(d, list) else [0, 0, 0] for d in out.value]

     id  day               value
0   120    0   [0.3, -0.5, -0.7]
1   120    1     [0.5, 3.4, 2.7]
2   120    2    [0.45, 3.4, 0.7]
3   120    3    [0.25, 0.4, 0.7]
4   120    4  [0.15, 0.34, 0.17]
5   121    0    [0.35, 3.4, 2.7]
6   121    1           [0, 0, 0]
7   121    2   [0.5, 3.44, 2.57]
8   121    3           [0, 0, 0]
9   121    4           [0, 0, 0]
10  345    0   [0.5, 0.34, 0.37]
11  345    1           [0, 0, 0]
12  345    2           [0, 0, 0]
13  345    3           [0, 0, 0]
14  345    4           [0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that each day (0 through 4) is mentioned somewhere in your dataframe at least once.

Make the id and the day a MultiIndex (`set_index`) and convert the dataframe into a table (`unstack`). There will be missing values (missing days for some id's), set them to zeros (`fillna`). Then convert the table back to a vector (`stack`) and convert the index back to the columns (`reset_index`).

```
df1 = df.set_index(['id', 'day']).unstack().fillna(0)\
        .stack().reset_index().astype(object)
```

The dataframe must be converted to the type `object`, otherwise the assignment of lists to a column won't work. Now, replace the 0s with the lists of your choice:

```
df1.loc[df1['value'] == 0, 'value'] = [[0, 0, 0]]
```

Note that you should assign a one-element list that contains your desired list.

Comment: will all missing days refer to the same list if you assign like that

Comment: @Sacry Yes, they will, I do not know if this is important for the OP.

Answer (score 1):

### Here is a way using `pandas.concat`

```
silly = pd.DataFrame(dict(day=range(5)))
dilly = pd.concat([
    d.merge(silly.assign(id=n), 'outer')
    for n, d in df.groupby('id')
], ignore_index=True)
willy = pd.Series([[0, 0, 0]] * len(dilly), dilly.index)
dilly.value.fillna(willy, inplace=True)

dilly

    day   id               value
0     0  120   [0.3, -0.5, -0.7]
1     1  120     [0.5, 3.4, 2.7]
2     2  120    [0.45, 3.4, 0.7]
3     3  120    [0.25, 0.4, 0.7]
4     4  120  [0.15, 0.34, 0.17]
5     0  121    [0.35, 3.4, 2.7]
6     2  121   [0.5, 3.44, 2.57]
7     1  121           [0, 0, 0]
8     3  121           [0, 0, 0]
9     4  121           [0, 0, 0]
10    0  345   [0.5, 0.34, 0.37]
11    1  345           [0, 0, 0]
12    2  345           [0, 0, 0]
13    3  345           [0, 0, 0]
14    4  345           [0, 0, 0]
```

---

### Using `pd.DataFrame` and `unstack`

```
pd.DataFrame(df.value.tolist(), [df.id, df.day]).unstack(fill_value=0).stack().pipe(
    lambda d: pd.Series(d.values.tolist(), d.index)
).reset_index(name='value')

     id  day               value
0   120    0   [0.3, -0.5, -0.7]
1   120    1     [0.5, 3.4, 2.7]
2   120    2    [0.45, 3.4, 0.7]
3   120    3    [0.25, 0.4, 0.7]
4   120    4  [0.15, 0.34, 0.17]
5   121    0    [0.35, 3.4, 2.7]
6   121    1     [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
7   121    2   [0.5, 3.44, 2.57]
8   121    3     [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
9   121    4     [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
10  345    0   [0.5, 0.34, 0.37]
11  345    1     [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
12  345    2     [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
13  345    3     [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
14  345    4     [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```